# If $f$:$\mathbb{R}^n$→$\mathbb{R}$* is measurable in each compact (the restriction of f to the compact,$f|_{A}$) prove that $f$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I´ve been working on this question some time but I am incapable of solving it, maybe someone can help me out. It says:

If $f$:$\mathbb{R}^n$→$\mathbb{R}$* is measurable in each compact ($f|_{A}$ measurable for each $A$ compact) prove that $f$ is measurable

Comment: Hint: Proof by contradiction. Use that there exists compact sets $K_n$ s.t. $$\Bbb R^n = \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} K_n $$

Comment: hint: to show that $f^{-1} (A) \subset \mathcal A$ for measurable $A \subset \mathbb R^*$ have a look at $\bigcup_k f_{\vert A_k}^{-1} (A)$ for $A_k = [-k,k]^n$.